# Line between Back-end and Front-end in web app development

Tags: node.js, frontend, backend, web-development-server

I have been learning full stack web development for a while now. But I am having trouble to understand where would the job of back-end developer stops, and front end begins when the work is separated.

I understand the back-end developer builds API that the front end developer will interact with, but I am confused regarding routing and (using nodeJS) who would write the equivalent of what is in the app.js file.

Finally, If you do back-end only, then you would not write any 'views.ejs' files?

Answer (score 4):

Frontend development deals solely with the parts of a web application that a user interacts with, and requires HTML, JavaScript and CSS. The backend deals with the server, the application logic, and database.

If a single frontend developer is building a simple web application, they will have to create both the front end and the backend of the application. This may just require creating routes to render pages. Most freelance web developers do this.

For much bigger applications (in bigger organisations), the duties of the frontend developer and the backend developer are much more distinct. A backend developer will be responsible for building the actual application logic, checking for authentication and authorization, managing the database etc. The frontend developer in this organisation will work solely to design the interface that the user interacts with. They will not be required to even render any page on the backend. This is the job of the backend developer.

In short, a front-end developer may have some basic knowledge about the backend, but a backend or full stack developer will be required to build all the features of the application that a user does not see.

You read more about the difference using the following link: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/i-dont-speak-your-language-frontend-vs-backend

Answer (score 0):

The difference between back-end and frond-end developers is the program they wrote. Front-end deal mostly with the physical apparance of the website. How it looks and what user can physically feel while using the website. Front end languages include HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

While [back-end developers](https://www.trusted5freelancesites.com/en/categories/back-end) focus mainly on the integration of server, web applications, and logic of the stylish web design made by front-end developers. They are in charge of creating a communication link between the website, the browser and the database servers.